# Custom WebApi Authorization Database Call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-model

I'm trying to decide if the custom Authorization attribute I wrote is really a good idea.

**Scenario**
Say we have a collection of stores, each `Store` has an owner. Only the owner of the store can do CRUD operations on the store. EXCEPT for users with a `Claim` that basically overrides the ownership requirement and says they can do CRUD operations on ANY store.

Sidenote: I'm using Thinktecture and ADFS

So I made a `StoreOwnerAuthorize` attribute who's parameters `("Manage", "Stores")` are used to check if the user has the appropriate claim to "override" not being an owner but still able to pass the authorization check.

I'm not sure how I feel about having a claim like "ManageStores" and making the database call inside the attribute. It makes me think I'm going down the wrong road, even though it does accomplish exactly what I need.

**API Routes**

```
api/v1/Store/{storeId:int:min(1)}/employees   
api/v1/Store/{storeId:int:min(1)}/inventory
```

**API Method**

```
[StoreOwnerAuthorize("Manage", "Stores")]
[ResourceAuthorize("View", "Store")]
[Route("")]
//api/v1/Store/{storeId:int:min(1)}/employees 
public IHttpActionResult GetStoreEmployees(int storeId)
{
    return Ok(collectionOfStoreEmployees);
}
```

**StoreOwnerAuthorizeAttribute**

```
public class StoreOwnerAuthorizeAttribute : ResourceAuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly DbContext _context = new DbContext();

    public StoreOwnerAuthorizeAttribute(){  }
    public StoreOwnerAuthorizeAttribute(string action, params string[] resources)
        : base(action, resources) { }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //If the user has the Claim that overrides the requirement that the user 
        //is the Owner of the Store, skip checking if they are the owner
        if (base.IsAuthorized(actionContext))
            return true;

        //Get route parameter to lookup Store and determine if the user is the owner
        object storeId;
        actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("storeId", out storeId);
        var isOwner = false;
        if (storeId != null)
        {
            isOwner =
                _context.Store_Get_ByStoreID(int.Parse(storeId.ToString()))
                    .Any(x => x.OwnerId == theUser.Id());
        }
        return isOwner;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just thinking about doing the same. Do you still use this type of authorization, of have you come up with something different?

Comment: Yep, so far I sill use the above.